# Installing Rundeck Kerberos Exec Plugin

Tags: rundeck

I have configured the [Kerberos executor plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/plugins/2015/03/17/kerb-node-executor.html) as a zip file in /libext directory.

But the plugin is not listed under Node Executors.

Is there any other configurations to be done for the plugin configurations.

Answer (score 0):

After copy the [zip](https://github.com/cernops/rundeck-exec-kerberos/releases/download/v1.4.1/rundeck-ssh-krb-node-executor-plugin-1.4.1.zip) file at libext directory, now you have a [new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIpBW.jpg) node executor for your projects named "SSH Kerberos Executor". Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKJ9L.jpg). (Tested under Rundeck 3.2.1).

If it doesn't work try restarting Rundeck and you'll see the new node executor for sure.

Comment: I am using Rundeck 3.0.22-20190512.If possible can you please share your zip file. So the i can compare with the file which i m having. 
"SSH Kerberos Executor" is not displayed under Default Node Executor under my project.